# Select the depth in SQL path using regex expression

Tags: python, regex, dataframe, amazon-athena

I am querying an S3 using Athena and I want to select the key until certain path level.
Here are some key examples:

- project=proj1/ID=SS02769/input=client1/version=X3900/data/fold1/file1.csv
- project=proj1/ID=SS02770/input=client1/version=X4500/data/fold1/file2.csv
- project=proj1/ID=SS02775/input=client1/version=X9000/data/fold1/file3.csv

I want to query these rows and select all the string until 'data/' is there any regex expression to use or any sql expression?
Actually I tried the next regex expression but does not work :

```
regex_match = fr'([^/]*[/]){{{depth}}}'
```

with depth=4 and with the next query :

```
f"SELECT REGEXP_EXTRACT(key,'{regex_match}') AS path FROM bucket_number_1)\
 GROUP BY REGEXP_EXTRACT(key, '{regex_match}')"
```

but I dot empty dataframe

Any help is appreciated !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
regex_match = r'^((?:[^/]*/){5})'
```

*Details*:

- `^` - start of string
- `((?:[^/]*/){5})` - Capturing group 1:

  - `(?:[^/]*/){5}` - five consecutive occurrences of
  - `[^/]*` - any zero or more chars other than a `/` char
  - `/` - a `/` char.